# What is the difference between a designated assist and a kill assist with the laser designator?

Tags: battlefield-3

Is the designated assist like just one javelin rocket going to a tank with full health or does it need to be completely destroyed? Is the kill assist one rocket or does it need to be completely destroyed also? Or is both the same of that way or the other way?

Answer (score 1):

The designated assist happens when target you designated is destroyed. 
The kill assist happens when you help killing the target. 
Example: You designated an enemy tank and killed 2 of the 3 players that were inside (1 run away) you get a designated assist and 2 kill assist.
That's what i understand of, at least xD